# Copy cells to new row

Tags: excel

I have three columns, A, B and D
Column A and B have integer numbers that Im trying to map to column D which looks something like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |  | 7 |
| 2 | 4 |  | 9 |

I want to populate column C with column D's data, but I need to look like bellow:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 7 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 7 | 9 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 |  |
| 4 | 4 | 7 |  |
| 5 | 3 | 7 |  |
| 1 | 4 | 9 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 9 |  |
| 3 | 4 | 9 |  |
| 4 | 3 | 9 |  |
| 5 | 4 | 9 |  |

I need to map column D and duplicate those numbers down to Column A and have Column C change every time Column A repeats to the first number, which in this case is 1

Comment: It looks like it is done.  Column A goes from 1 to 5; column B alternates between 3 and 4; and column C repeats 7 or 9 and changes when column A is 1.  What else is there?  Are there more requirements?

Comment: I want to populate column C with column D's data based on the repeat of column A: 1,2,3,4,5 so column C would populate 7, 9 ect... every time 1 repeats

Comment: do you just want to put 5 7's and then 5 9's and continue, or is this a formula that needs to work in multiple scenarios?

Comment: A formula that needs to work in multiple scenerios